# How can some elements in matrix representation that satisfies a cutoff function be deleted in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

```
X=(-5:.5:5)
Z=(-3:.5:3)
[x z]=meshgrid(X,Z)
```

The cutoff function that must delete the wanted elements is a circle with radius 1
    (x-1)^2+(z-1)^2<=1
How can we manage a loop to put those elements 0 in the output data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
for i=1:size(x,1)
   for j=1:size(x,2)
      if ((x(i,j)-1)^2+(z(i,j)-1)^2<=1)
          x(i,j) = 0;
          y(i,j) = 0;
      end
   end
end
```

I hope this code is easy enough for you to understand what it does - if not you should take a programming class somewhere or sit down with a book.

Now, if the above answer is what you were looking for, take my word for it that gnovice's answer (a mix of [edit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6253345/2) and [edit 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6253345/3) actually) showed the way how to do this much smarter in MATLAB:

```
radius = 1;
index = (x-1).^2 + (z-1).^2 <= radius^2;  %# Logical index of elements inside the circle
x(index) = 0;  %# Set the x values inside the circle to 0
z(index) = 0;  %# Set the z values inside the circle to 0
```

Hope this helps - otherwise I'm giving up ;-).

Answer (score 3):

I'm first going to assume that `x` and `z` represent the coordinates at which some 2-D function `f` will be evaluated to generate your output. Given that `x` and `z` end up being 13-by-21 matrices in your example, your output from `f` should be 13-by-21 as well. You can then find a [logical index](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1) indicating the points that are inside your circle and use this index to set the points in the output matrix to be zero:

```
output = f(x,z);  %# Compute your output, which should be a 13-by-21 matrix
index = (x-1).^2 + (z-1).^2 <= 1;  %# Logical index of elements inside the circle
output(index) = 0;  %# Set the output values inside the circle to 0
```

Comment: @gnovice: in this edited version I can't see x,why?I think the previous answer was better,because I want to emit 12 elements of the matrix that can be composed with the above boundary(I mean x & z).but the output was a 13_by_21 matrix that the other elements are 1.should I add some command to that code?

Comment: @Shabnam: You have to be a little clearer. What exactly do you want to get as a result? A 13-by-21 matrix for `x` and `z` with values outside the circle set to 0, or just the set of 12 `x` and `z` values inside the circle?

Comment: @gnovice: the elements of the matrix that is made of X=(-5:.5:5)
Z=(-3:.5:3),[x z]=meshgrid(X,Z) are different numbers in the range of -5 to 5 for x and -3 to 3 for z,I want to emit those elements that their x or z or both of them are <=1

Comment: @Shabnam: in your comment you say "x or z or both of them are <=1" - so what you want to set to zero is not a circle but a rectangle! (Or a circle in a non-euclidean norm, in case you are a mathematician). Also the circle that you give in your question was centered around the point x=1,z=1 instead of the origin - was that intended?

Comment: @Jonas Heidelberg: As you know the equation mentioned in the question represents a circle around(1,1) and I want to emit the effects of the potential of a point charge"placed at(1,0,1)" around that point with a radius of 1,because of that I want to delete the points in the disk mentioned. note that in this case we work in the cartesian coordinate on the Z_X plane .In brief,I want to REPLACE those matrix elements that satisfy the circle equation with (0,0)

Comment: @Shabnam: I tried to revise my answer to better address your comments. Is it what you were looking for?

Comment: @gnovice: sorry ,but what's f(x,z) ?

Comment: @Shabnam: okay, so judging by your question and your third comment, the end of your second comment is imprecise to the point of being wrong. Apart from that, gnovices answer in his second or third version should answer your problem - otherwise you need to EDIT your question to provide more than three lines of code so that we can figure out at what point the answer doesn't match what you want/need.

Comment: @Shabnam: `f(x,z)` in gnovice's answer is metacode: it stands for whatever YOU want to be in the output variable from which you want to remove the circle. If you want to remove the circle from x and z, then you would run the code twice, once replacing `f(x,z)` with `x` and then with `z`. If you calculate some force as a function of x and z, `f(x,z)` would be the formula for calculating that force... does that help anything at all?

Comment: @Jonas Heidelberg: I think if I explain the whole question here,I will complicate matter more,so I think of bringing a simple example here and try to reach my answer this way.If it's amateur please excuse me.imagin:

Comment: @Jonas Heidelberg:                                                   imagine:X=[-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3;-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3;-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3] and              Z=[-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3;-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3;-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 ].Now,I want to replace the elements of meshgrid of these two matrixes with zero from X=1 with radius 1 and from Z=1 with the same radius.I mean if X is 0 ,1 or 2 put 0 and if Z is 0 ,1 or 2 put 0 in the output.the circle equation must be used in the code therefore this process can be done for any Radius.I think of a simple for loop but I can't manage it.Don't you think so?